# How do position operators ($\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, $\hat{z}$, $\hat{r}$) act on orbital angular momentum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

Consider an orbital angular momentum state $\vert l,m\rangle$, I am pretty sure when $\hat{r} = \sqrt{\hat{x}^2 + \hat{y}^2 + \hat{z}^2}$ and $\hat{z}$ act on it, the resulting states will still be $\vert l, m\rangle$, since $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{z}$ both commute with $L_z$ and $L^2$. However, I don't know what what are the resulting states of $\hat{y}\vert l, m\rangle$ and $\hat{x}\vert l, m\rangle$, as $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ both do not commute with $L_z$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the action of $x,y,z$ on $|l,m\rangle$ you need to use the Clebsh-Gordon  procedure for combining the $l=1$ vector defined by $x-iy \sim |l=1,m=-1\rangle$,  $z\sim |l=1,m=0\rangle$, $x+iy\sim |l=1,m=+1\rangle$ to the $|l,m\rangle$ state. You will get a linear combination  of $l-1$, $l$, $l+1$

Comment: Do you mean a linear combination of $m - 1$ and $m + 1$?

Comment: Not exactly: $(x\pm iy)|l,m\rangle$ will be a $|l' ,m\pm 1\rangle$, but $l'$ can be $l-1$, $l$, or $l+1$.